# Proving that $H=\mbox{ker}(T)\oplus\mbox{lin}\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ when $T$ is of finite rank

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $T:H\to H$ be an operator of  finite rank; $\mbox{dim}\,\mbox{ran}(T)=:n$. Show that there exists an orthonormal system  $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in H$ such that $H=\mbox{ker}(T)\oplus\mbox{lin}\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$, and there exists $y_1,\ldots,y_n\in H$  such that
\begin{equation*}
 Tx=\sum_{i=1}^ny_i(x,x_i).
 \end{equation*}
We can see the existence of $y_i$ is easy to show since we can write $y_i=T x_i$. Since $H= Ker T\oplus \mbox{lin}\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$, for every $x= z+ \lambda_1 x_1+ \cdots+\lambda_n x_n$ with $z\in Ker T$ and $\lambda_i= (x, x_i)$

Thus $$Tx= \lambda_1 y_1+ \cdots+\lambda_n y_n$$

How to show that $H=\mbox{ker}(T)\oplus\mbox{lin}\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$?

Answer (score 1):

$Tx=\sum \lambda_iTx_i$ so $x-\sum \lambda_ix_i \in Ker (T)$. Call this $u$. Then $x=u+\sum \lambda_ix_i  \in Ker (T)+lin\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$. Now prove that if $z \in lin\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ and $z \in Ker (T)$ then $z=0$.